# How to give SD Card File Path in following Code?

Tags: android

How to give SD Card File Path in following Code?

```
String s="file:///sdcard/tempImage.png";
parameters.putString("attachment","{\"name\":\"Android Facebook application By Martin\",\"href\":\"http://www.google.com/\",\"caption\":\"By google Technology \",\"description\":\"Description :- Android and iphone application \",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\'"+ s + "',\"href\":\"http://s.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"for more tips click here\",\"href\":\"http://www.google.com/\"}}}");
```

I use Above Code for Upload Image on Facebook Wall from my SD Card. But the Above Code is not Work, Please Help me.

Comment: file:///sdcard/tempImage.png is URI, not file path.

Comment: Hi, Jett Hsieh Then What is File Path of SD Card ?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), tempImage.png);
```

Comment: DO insure if the path is correct using Log.e("File exists", ""mFile.exist()); and if returns true then there is some other problem

Comment: File is Exist on My SD Card Because I used this File is Upload to Twitter Also.

Comment: Then the problem is in your Uploading process and unfortunately I dont know how to do that so cant help in that scenario

Comment: If i used Image Directly From Web then this is Completely Work.

Comment: instead of creating string try by passing as mFile.path() might work

Answer (score 1):

```
String filePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/tempImage.png";
File mFile = new File(filePath);
```

Comment: Yes I check it, The Path Print is "/mnt/sdcard/tempImage.png".

Comment: keep your file in SDCard directly. what is *mnt*?.

Comment: Hi Hotveryspicy, I check this But this is not Work.

Comment: if U have any Different Suggestion, Please Give Me, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No Error is Displayed, Text is Upload Completely But Image is Not Upload